# option select in razor can't work for me

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This code doesn't work for me:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.etattik, 
    new SelectList(new List<Object>
    { 
      new { value = 0 , text="text1"  },
      new { value = 1 , text = "text2" },
      new { value = 2 , text = "text3"}
    })
  )
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.etattik)
</div>
```

It shows me `{ value = 0 , text=text1  }`

Comment: What do you expect it to show?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the `dataValueField` and `dataTextField` for `SelectList`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
                        m => m.etattik, 
                        new SelectList(
                                  new List<Object>{ 
                                   new { value = 0 , text="text1"  },
                                new { value = 1 , text = "text2" },
                                  new { value = 2 , text = "text3"}
                                }
                    , "value", "text")
                        )
```

Comment: how does he/she validates `m.etattik`?

Comment: I have just added the code for dropdown list, the validation remains as it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.test,
                        new List<SelectListItem>(){
                         new SelectListItem() { Value = "0", Text = "text1" },
                         new SelectListItem() { Value = "1" , Text="text2" },
                         new SelectListItem() { Value = "2" , Text="text3" }
                        }
                        )
```